# Making a button change the webview

Tags: xcode, macos, webview

I'm trying to make a mac app using the apple developer tools, specifically xcode. I'm basically imbedding my website into in in a sort of iTunes-esque way- side bar at right, user clicks a button on side bar and webview web page changes. Problem is I'm having trouble trying to get the button to load a specific URL into the webview.

Comment: @Bavarious Since I'm not the most killed at xcode I tried linking the button to a text box hidden behind the webview. The text box held the URL of the page and when the button was clicked this URL is loaded into the webview. Not a very effective way but I found that it did work.

Comment: You could have a dictionary mapping button titles (or button tags) to URLs instead of using textfields to hold URL strings. But now I’m confused: you’ve just said that it works, so what isn’t working?

Comment: @Bavarious It does work...sometimes. Other times it will refuse to load. I was looking for a more stable approach. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebView* webView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];

NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.example.com”;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

So you first get the url as a string, turn it into an NSURL object, and then into an NSURLRequest object and finally give that to the webview object to load. You could also do this with a webview created in Interface Builder by ommiting the first line (where the webview is being initialised) and make sure you add the webView property to the viewcontroller as an IBOutlet and connecting it to the webview in Interface Builder.

**Edit:** It seems I was using iPhone syntax for the webview. Loading a url on a mac webview however is still similar, so all I've changed is the class name.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better that how I was doing it.

Comment: Oh, I apologise for that. I skipped ahead to answering it and didn't notice I was answering the wrong question. =S I've edited my post accordingly.